# regex replace just the last charater of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

This should be an easy one and I couldn't find it anywhere.
How do I replace just the last character of a string with a char from an array?

```
str1 = str1.replace(?????, myArray[b]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` matches the end of a string, `.` matches any character

```
const replaceLast = (str, replace) => str.replace(/.$/, replace);
replaceLast('cat', 'r');
```

But you should probably use string functions for this:

```
const replaceLast = (str, replace) => str.slice(0, -1) + replace;
replaceLast('cat', 'r');
```

Comment: what is the \z I saw somwhwere?

Comment: `$` matches at the end of linebreaks.  `\z` matches the end of input.

Comment: ...But `\z` is not supported in javascript. It uses `$` for end of input.

Answer (score 9):

You could try the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method:

```
str1 = str1.substring(0, str1.length - 1) + myArray[b];
```

Comment: Best to avoid Regexp if you can, standard string manipulation is much faster - +1

Comment: +1, no need for regex since you're not caring _what_ you're replacing, just _where_

Comment: You beat me to it :-) but _s_ is not defined.

Comment: @darin-dimitrov ... is that a goof with the s.length? Should it be str1?

Comment: If he still wants to use replace, it can be done without regex: `str1 = str1.replace(str1.charAt(str1.length-1), myArray[b]);`

Comment: I like string better but I thought regex was faster... you guys are sure strings are better method??

Comment: @leon, good catch, I've replaced `s` by `str1` in my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Ravan: What if the last character appears multiple times in string?

Comment: No Fail... last character only, multiples or anything else before it does not matter